# How to rearrange XML nodes using PHP DOM?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need to re-arrange the table_data nodes in a perscribed order using PHP DOM.

For example, given the XML below I need the table data arranged in the
following order:

```
bugs_status
attachments
bugs
Version
```

So, this XML needs to go from this:

```
<database name="foodatabase">
   <table_data name="Version">
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="attachments">
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="bugs">
       <row> 
           <field name="problem_id">7</field>
           <field name="problem">Something is broken</field>
       </row>
       <row> 
           <field name="problem_id">8</field>
           <field name="problem">Something else is broken</field>
       </row>
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="bugs_status">
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">1</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">5</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Acknowledged</field>
       </row>
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">2</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">10</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Feedback</field>
       </row>
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">3</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">20</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Client Confirmation</field>
       </row>
   </table_data>
</database>
```

to this:

```
 <database name="foodatabase">
   <table_data name="bugs_status">
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">1</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">5</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Acknowledged</field>
       </row>
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">2</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">10</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Feedback</field>
       </row>
       <row>
           <field name="bugs_status_id">3</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_priority">20</field>
           <field name="bugs_status_name">Client Confirmation</field>
       </row>
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="attachments">
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="bugs">
       <row> 
           <field name="problem_id">7</field>
           <field name="problem">Something is broken</field>
       </row>
       <row> 
           <field name="problem_id">8</field>
           <field name="problem">Something else is broken</field>
       </row>
   </table_data>
   <table_data name="Version">
   </table_data>
</database>
```

Notice that the table_data nodes and their child nodes are moved together. This is important because we are re-arranging these tables and their rows to satisfy foreign key relationships.

Conceptually, this isn't hard, invert the list, and then re-arrange them by searching for each node in the list, and placing it before the first child of the  element.

My problem is: I can't figure out how to grab a specified node, remove it from its current position, and place it before the first child.

Comment: In theory the order of XML nodes shouldn't matter since in this case xpath queries will always work independently of order. If you're just looping through the XML and rely on an ordering then how you achieve this will depend on your XML reader lib you're using.

Comment: [PHPUnit fails to import the database](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#database.beware-of-foreign-keys) information properly unless you order the tables that host foreign keys above the tables that need them. I solved it by passing the tables in the correct order to mysqldump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the goal was to re-arrange the XML nodes in a specific order, the answer turned out to be to specify those tables **in that order** when dumping them from MySQL to start with.

Given the required table order, C, D, A, B, the command is then:

```
sudo mysqldump --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf --xml -t  foodatabase C D A B > /path/to/file.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that this is a bad design, since you rely on a specific structure of your XML. This will give you a headache later on.

Maybe instead, you should make an array and sort the array with the keys of your XML and then grab the XML nodes in that order.

If you load the XML with the SimpleXML class in PHP, this should not be difficult.

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php <= Take a look in the manual.

Comment: In my efforts to be concise in my question, I concealed the fact that I am, indeed, using arrays to pre-sort all this data. But, I'm open to suggestoins on how to improve it. "Grabbing the nodes in the order I want" is not really an option since this is for use as a test data set with PHPUnit. So, I need to have a resulting XML file with the nodes in the specified order, or else I cannot satisfy the foreign key relationships (I have already written the code that determines foreign key precedence by examining the db). I started with SimpleXML, but it ended up making more sense to use PHP DOM.\

Comment: The point of my comment above is to give background and explain that I need a resulting XML document that has the nodes in the specified order because PHPUnit will not "grab the nodes in a specified order." It loads them in the order in which they are in the XML file. This is a pain to do by hand, thus, I am scripting it to automate the process.